# Adding bootstrap alerts to javascript on success function

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to be able to add a bootstrap feedback banner like the link below into the code that I have, however any time I try to add a banner it doesnt appear and I am getting no errors in the console.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp

```
success: function(data) {
        console.log("added");
        alert("This was successfully added");
      },
```

I am new to this so if anyone has any ideas how I can complete this please let me know. Thanks so much

Comment: Where is the html? the alert that you are using in the code is the native alert function, nothing about bootstrap alert

Comment: @CalvinNunes I don't have any html, I just have that function in the success part.  I know, but I want the alert to become a bootstrap success alert

Comment: you are confusing Javascript alert with Bootstrap CSS Alert... they are very different... you can't use the boostrap alert to style the JS native alert. Bootstrap alert is used in HTML elements, adding its class to the element, so that element become styled

Comment: You have all the markings of a [help vampire](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm). Perhaps take a step back, read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and then revisit your question. What you're trying to do is very clearly documented and is easily searchable.

Comment: @CalvinNunes look at the answer, this is something like I am trying to do, however this message is being displayed all the time, I only want it to be displayed when the success function is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments on your question, you are confusing JS native `alert()` with bootstrap CSS alert class...

bootstrap is applied to HTML elements, so in order to use it, you need to have an HTML element with the alert class on it...

the code below shows the difference and also shows a tip on how to use the bootstrap alert like a popup alert.

```js
function showAlerts(){
  document.getElementById('bootstrap-alert').style.display = 'block';
  setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('bootstrap-alert').style.display = 'none'}, 1700);
  
  //THIS IS JS ALERT
  alert('success! (JS alert)');
}
```

```css
#bootstrap-alert{
  margin: auto;
  width: 280px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="showAlerts()">Show Alerts</button>
<br>

<!-- THIS IS BOOTSTRAP ALERT -->
<div class='alert alert-success' style='display:none' id='bootstrap-alert'>
  Success! (div with Bootstrap alert class)
</div>
```

If you know how to use jQuery, you can use `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` functions (link to examples: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp)  to show the bootstrap alert in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is html, css based, not JS function. 
To show such type of alerts, you can package like toastr. 
another way is to add bootstrap alert in your html like, notice the hidden class, by default it will be hidden, show it when you have ajax response

```
<style>
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
</style>
<div class="alert alert-success hidden"><strong>Success!</strong><span></span> </div>

success: function(data) {
              $('.alert-success span').text(data.message).removeClass('hidden');
    // first add message to your alert, then remove hidden class;
}
```

Comment: this is shown all the time though, I just want it to be shown when the action is preformed and the success function is called. When ever I first view the page it is displayed

Comment: I have added a 'hidden' class, So it will not visible.

Comment: no it is visible. I copied your code exactly and it is visible